# Вопрост про SVN (TORTOISE)

Tags: svn

Всем привет. Решил освоить SVN. Сразу возникли вопросы:

1. Разрабатываю сайт, залил его в репозиторий (trunks). Дальше не пойму: если я хочу дальше разрабатывать этот сайт я делаю его рабочую копию на сервере?
2. Как запустить главный проект в репозитории? Что бы понять сработали ли изменения на нем или нет, работает ли он вообще и т.п.

Всем кто ответит огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```
svn co https://your_repository_path/trunk .
```

на серваке, настраиваем svn up в crontab и работаем. Теперь ваши коммиты будут через некоторое время (интервал запуска svn up в кроне) будут на боевом сервере.

P.S. точка вконце команды svn co - это не завершение фразы, а именно точка, иначе на сервере еще создасться папка trunk и все данные будут помещены в нее

Comment: Я конечно же оценил ваш гений и талант краткого ответа. Но не могли бы вы пояснить мне на языке смертных пару не знакомых слов, которыми вы меня обложили:  svn up в crontab.
Если вы читали мой вопрос, там явно указано, что я только начал изучать SVN и также указано, что я использую интерфейс tortoise. Ком. строку пока не пользую для этих целей. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На java как то так:

1. Есть копия проекта в репозитории;
2. Есть локальная рабочая копия, которую периодически надо синхронизировать с копией в репозитории;
3. Когда нужно, делается сборка проекта, которая разворачивается на сервере.
   В репозитории ничего запускать не надо, там просто хранятся файлы проекта.

Comment: 1.То есть получается рабочая копия проекта хранится должна где-то на сервере (в моем случае apache) чтобы иметь возможность её запускать. Я правильно вас понял? 
2. Под сборкой  проекта на сервере вы имеете ввиду конечного рабочего проекта?